# Rails test fails to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, minitest, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I've encountered a strange issue with tests in Rails 6.1.3.1. I've created a file for generating various stats about my data, which is in `lib/modules/stats.rb`. I've added a test file in `test/modules/stats_test.rb` which runs this test, and I have 100% coverage.

These stats could be used in various places, one of which would be in a Rake task. So, I have created `lib/tasks/stats.rake`, along these lines:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/modules/stats.rb"
include Stats

namespace :stats do

  desc 'Print all the stats'
  task :print => [:environment] do
    stats = StatsMethods.generate_all_the_stats
    puts stats
  end

end
```

By virtue of the first line of this file existing, `rake test` no longer runs `test/modules/stats_test.rb`; coverage drops proportionately. What's going on here?

Comment: What's the output of `rake test`? What's the output when you run that test file by itself?

Comment: The tests output is as expected, without any warnings, whether I run together or separately; the only difference is the drop in coverage when running them all.

Comment: What's your coverage tool? With many you can generate a report that tells you how its calculating. What does it think is now untested, and do you agree?

Comment: According to the Gemfile it's simplecov, simplecov-lcov and rails-controller-testing. Once refactored (see answer below) all is covered.

Comment: If changing this file changes test coverage, then what does the test look like that's supposed to be covering it?

Comment: like any other test; `require 'test_helper'`, `include Stats`, `class StatsTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase`, then a variety of tests for each different calculation.

Comment: Makes sense. I noticed that the name of the task changed between the question and answer; I'm curious if that affected coverage. Sharing the test in the question could help explain coverage changes.

Comment: As part of refactoring I changed the name to something I preferred, but I don't think that's the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring as follows resolved the issue, though I don't know why (suggestions welcome):

```
namespace :stats do

  desc 'Generate all the stats'
  task :generate => [:environment] do
    require File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'modules', 'stats.rb')
    include Stats
    stats = StatsMethods.generate_all_the_stats
    puts stats
  end

end
```